# Stripe Webhook: How to link Stripe customer to my customer?

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe's Webhook to set up a Checkout session to be notified about important events.

I create a Session and redirect client to subscribe to a plan successfully. And I get events in my webhook, including "customer.created" which has information about a Stripe customer.

How can I link this Strip's Customer object to my internal customer? I can specify some metadata and cient_reference_id when I create a session but they are not accessible during "customer.created" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is to [create the customer object manually](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) prior to creating the checkout session. This way you can easily link the customer in your database with the Stripe Customer object. You can then [pass in this Customer object's ID when creating the checkout session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-customer).

Comment: Yep. That's what I ended up doing. I thought, when creating a session, maybe there is a way to pass some metadata (e.g. internal pk) to be attached to the created customer so that when it is created, I can use that to link Stripe customer to mine. That way, the code would be cleaner and I didn't have to create a customer in case user returns without doing anything.

Answer (score 1):

But that means creating a stripe account for all my users. 99% does not take a paying subscription..